# Python throws the error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Tags: python, runtime-error

```
#imports
import pygame
#globals
SCREENWIDTH = 800
SCREENHEIGHT = 480

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):
    #relevant variables
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
    level = None

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__()
        self.width = 25
        self.height = 25
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color('RED'))

    def update(self):
        """ Move the player. """
        # Move left/right
        self.rect.x += self.change_x


        # See if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right,
            # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
            self.change_x = 0

        # Move up/down
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

            # Stop our vertical movement
            self.change_y = 0

    def go_left(self):
        self.change_x = -1

    def go_right(self):
        self.change_x = 1

    def go_up(self):
        self.change_y = -1

    def go_down(self):
        self.change_y = 1

    def stop(self):
        self.change_x = 0

#collideable object
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    level = None

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color('Yellow'))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
#collideable object that will later take players to different rooms
class Door(Wall):
    level = None
    def __init__(self):
        Wall.__init__()
        self.width = 5
        self.height = 30

class Level(object):

    background = None

    world_shift_x = 0
    world_shift_y=0
    level_limit_x = -1000
    level_limit_y = -2000

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.door_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def update(self):
        self.wall_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()
        self.door_list.update()

    def draw(self):
        screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
        self.wall_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)
        self.door_list.draw(screen)

    def shift_world(self, shift_x, shift_y):
        #scrolls the screen at a speed of "shift x or y"
        self.world_shift_x += shift_x
        self.world_shift_y += shift_y
        #shifts items within the world with the world
        for wall in self.wall_list:
            wall.rect.x += shift_x
            wall.rect.y += shift_y

        for door in self.door_list:
            door.rect.x += shift_x
            door.rect.y += shift_y

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            enemy.rect.x += shift_x
            enemy.rect.y += shift_y

class Level01(Level):
    #test level
    def __init__(self,player):
        Level.__init__()
        self.level_limit_x = -1000
        self.level_limit_y = -2000

        level = [[200,800,0,SCREENHEIGHT],
                 [200,600,50,SCREENHEIGHT],
                 [850,200,50,0],
                 [600,200,50,-50]
                 ]

        for wall in level:
            block = Wall(wall[0], wall[1])
            block.x = wall[2]
            block.y = wall[3]
            block.player = player
            self.wall_list.add(wall)

def main():
    pygame.init()

    size = [SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    player = Player()

    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))

    current_levelno = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)


    done = False

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_d and player.change_x > 0:
                    player.stop()

        active_sprite_list.update()

        current_level.update()

        if player.rect.right >= 380:
            diff_x = player.rect.right - 380
            player.rect.right = 380
            current_level.shift_world(-diff_x)

        if player.rect.left <= 120:
            diff_x = 120 - player.rect.left
            player.rect.left = 120
            current_level.shift_world(diff_x)

        if player.rect.bottom <= 700:
            diff_y = player.rect.bottom - 700
            player.rect.bottom = 700
            current_level.shift_world(-diff_y)

        if player.rect.top >= 100:
            diff_y = 100 - player.rect.bottom
            player.rect.bottom = 100
            current_level.shift_world(diff_y)



        current_position = player.rect.x + current_level.world_shift
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            if current_level_no < len(level_list)-1:
                player.rect.x = 120
                current_level_no += 1
                current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
                player.level = current_level
            else:
                done = True

        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        clock.tick(60)

        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The endgame of this code is to make a functional top down game with the goals of being a psychological horror. So far the mechanics in play are collision with walls, and, by extension, doors, levels, and character movements. 
In total, all I can tell anyone is that this error has to do with everything in the code that isn't globals and imports(unless I'm wrong, which would make more sense to me.), and that it has something to do with
A) Code line 140
B) Throws the error under the specific line under `'sprite.py`' that says `'self.add(*group) (which is line 142 in the 'sprite.py' file)`
The stuff I can speculate about in this is that perhaps the code is throwing an infinite loop, as watching the console shows a code in the IDLE Shell, or the messages section of the pyscripter(what I'm using to program this), which iterates indefinitely before the program terminates. No visuals are created, and nothing appears to be happening, save the infinite loop. The code message is 'File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add self.add(*group) I can't say for sure, it's probably better that you run the code yourself to see what you can gather.

Comment: Can you give us the ends of the traceback (skip over the likely ~1000 repetitions of the same thing…), instead of describing it in vague terms?

Comment: Also, can you fix your code to match the indentation of your actual code? Because we can't run it ourselves as posted. And strip out all the stuff that isn't relevant to reproducing your problem, so we don't have to read through a couple hundred lines of code that won't help debugging? (See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on doing that.)

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to—and shouldn't—create class attributes (like `wall_list = None`) for every instance attribute you're going to create in `__init__` (like `self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group`).

Comment: Also, `self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group` isn't going to create a new sprite group; it's going to assign the sprite group _class_ to `self.wall_list`, which is unlikely to be very useful. You probably wanted `pygame.sprite.Group()`. And I'm guessing if you did that three times, you did similar things in other places.